# Remove space between home indicator to custom textview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I tried to remove the left margin of the icon OR the right margin of the text (i dont really sure).
I added layout bounded so you can see the problem easily.

Im not using a Toolbar. So i look for solution for ActionBar.

[image: Screenshot with layout bounded]

In my code:

```
   actionBar  = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom_layout);
                actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.ic_top_bar_back));
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
            }
```

R.layout.action_bar_custom_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_custom_layout_textview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    andrpod:text="@string/notes"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: Try playing with `app:contentInsetStart=56dp` in `<Toolbar .../>` set it to different values (try 56dp, 72dp, etc.) and see the effect.

Comment: I suggest using [Toolbar widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: But im not using toolbar. Im using AppCompatActivity actionbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to make a ***customize AppBar***.As it will be useful for you in future.

This will **help** you so much.

***http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html***

Answer (score 0):

That's not your fault. This space is by default when you use the default toolbar. That's why making a custom toolbar will be good for you. See the image I also got the same problem as yours. If you see your layout in blue print mode you'll get to know that the place is by default.

[image]

Comment: Ok. but how can i remove the default space?

Comment: It's hard to find. Because i've gone through many websites but still didn't got the answer.

Comment: Yeah i know. thats why i asked here :)

Comment: heyy @motis10 try to add `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` in `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` tag

Comment: But im not using Toolbar. Im using ActionBar with customView

Comment: What do you mean? in my TextView? to add app:contentInsetStart="0dp"? It wont work